# Make a tkinter messagebox optional

Tags: tkinter

What I want is to make a tkinter message box with my own options.

It is like options with "OK", "Never" or Other options.
Thanks in advance

I have tried making a toplevel window na placing, but I want it different. I want it to flash if I click on the Tk window and get the minimize button removed (maximize button too, if possible).

Comment: create your own using the `Toplevel` widget (NOT `Tk`), then you can customize it as you wish

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change those buttons, but you can create your own!

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Label
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM, E
import playsound as pl    # pip install playsound if you don't have it
import threading as th
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Custom errors and warnings.")

def play_errorsound():
    pl.playsound("C:\Windows\Media\Windows Foreground.wav")

def place_center(master, geometry_x, geometry_y):
    rx = master.winfo_screenwidth()
    ry = master.winfo_screenheight()
    x = int((rx/2) - (500/2))
    y = int((ry/2) - (500/2))
    master.geometry(f"{geometry_x}x{geometry_y}+{x}+{y}")

def blink():
    errwin.grab_set()
    th.Thread(target=play_errorsound).start()
    for i in range(10):
        errwin.config(bg="blue")
        time.sleep(0.005)
        errwin.config(bg="white")
    errwin.grab_release()

def blink_start(event):
    th.Thread(target=blink).start()

def showerror(title, message, buttontext, buttoncommand):
    global errwin
    th.Thread(target=play_errorsound).start()
    errwin = Toplevel()
    errwin.transient(root)
    place_center(errwin, 400, 200)
    errwin.resizable(0, 0)
    errwin.title(title)
    text = Label(errwin, text=message, font="Calibri 15")
    text.pack(pady=5)
    b = Button(errwin, text=buttontext, command=buttoncommand)
    b.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)
    root.bind("<Button-1>", blink_start)

def close():
    root.quit()

b1 = Button(root, text="Show error", command=lambda: showerror("Error", "This is an error!", "Close this window", close))
b1.pack(pady=20)

place_center(root, 500, 500)

root.mainloop()
```

You can add more buttons if you want.

Comment: I have tried this, but I want it different. I want it to flash if I click on the Tk window and get the minimize button removed (maximize button too, if possible).

Comment: By following my code, the minimize and maximize buttons are already gone. For the blinking effect, you can use ```root.bind``` and bind it to a function. The function may include ```top.config(bg="color")```

Comment: Yes, something useful, Thanks in advance

Comment: It's already useful. Okay, check the updated code.